# Super Key doesn't work on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have Kubuntu 12.04 installed on HP 430 Notebook PC. My problem is that when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> nothing happens. Some of my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys did not work either. 
I have changed the Keyboard Model in System Settings>Hardware>Input Devices>Keyboard to Hewlett Packard Internet keyboard but doesn't seems to help. I have also Compiz-Config-Setting-Manager installed but I don't know how to make the right keyboard setting. 
I would like to have <kbd>Super</kbd> launch Start Menu Launcher as in MS-Windows, is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried Keyboard Shortcuts under system settings?

Comment: Yes, I've look to the System Settings>Global Keyboard Shortcuts>KDE Component:KWin but **couldn't** find any setting for Start Menu Launcher.   I did find some other customization settings for hotkeys, e.g. I can set 'Show Desktop' with Meta+D combination. Any other suggestions mate?

Comment: Have you tried custom shortcuts?

Comment: I've followed your step but I got two problems.  First, the shortcut input didn't accept only one key (super key). It just show 'Meta+' and then disappear. I suppose that it wants me to make a combination key 'Meta+something'.  Second, I didn't know what command/URL should I put in 'Action' form.  I thought that it should refer to 'kickoff launcher' but I couldn't find any file named 'kickoff' in */usr/bin*.  I'm sorry, I'm a newb here ...

Comment: (in Ubuntu 12.04) You need to tap 'fast enough' in order to get dash, since if your tap is too slow nothing happens. (and if it's slow enough, you see the shortcut thing)

Answer (score 2):

I'm beginning see the picture here, an article explain that ..

> The 'Windows Key' (as I call it), more properly known as the “meta
>   key”, is simply a modifier (like Shift, Ctrl, & Alt) and not a key in
>   its own right. This means that you cannot, without some lower level
>   file hacking, stab the Windows Key alone and get it to open the
>   launcher.

So this is how we do it :

1. Right click on Kickoff (the KDE icon in the bottom left of your
   screen)
2. Click “Application Launcher Settings”
3. Select “Keyboard Shortcuts”
4. Click the button and press your desired shortcut keycombo
5. Done!

source : [LINK](http://snowulf.com/2012/03/08/kde-windows-key-to-open-kickoff-launcher/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Super</kbd>, is a modifier (like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>) and not a key in its own right and you cannot, without some lower level file hacking, stab <kbd>Super</kbd> alone and get it to open the launcher.

But you can map <kbd>Super</kbd> to a virtual key like here:

1. in `.kde/Autostart` folder create a file
2. write bellow command in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xmodmap -e 'keycode 133=F13'
   ```
3. and make it exutable and run it
4. now you can right click on launcher and change shortkey to `left
   super key` named by <kbd>F13</kbd>

Comment: This approach will let you show the launcher as long as you press the meta key, but as you release it, the menu will drop.