# How do I open the Application Launcher on KDE with just the meta ("Windows") key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu

How do I open the application launcher ("start menu") of Kubuntu with my Windows key? Similar to how the Start menu in Windows is opened. I don't want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: you can also use this  http://askubuntu.com/a/611501/340792

Comment: Despite [overwhelming popular support since 2009, opening the launcher with Super/Win still not implemented in KDE](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=39073)!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### About modifier keys

Modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and also the <kbd>Meta</kbd> (also called "Super" or "Windows" key, are meant to operate only as *modifier* keys. This design works its way down to the roots of all the libraries under the GUI you see using KDE: Qt, Xorg, etc.

Your **exact** question is here on the KDE Forums by the way: [Super key to load Application Menu](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=39073).

#### ksuperkey

It seems however, that there's a large audience for this feature. So, in case you really want this to work, you could try the [`ksuperkey`](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey) package, which contains all you need:

> ksuperkey allows you to open the application launcher in KDE Plasma < 5.8 using the Super key (also known as the "Windows key"). If you hold down the Super key it will still act as a modifier key, allowing you to use it for other keyboard shortcuts.
>
> ksuperkey is a small application that runs in the background as a daemon. It was forked from xcape by Albin Olsson: https://github.com/alols/xcape

`ksuperkey` can be installed from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emehanik/+archive/ubuntu/ksuperkey).

Note that KDE Plasma 5.8 and above will support this feature by default.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow it was soo easy with Ubuntu. I appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a way to assign this to a hot corner, like in gnome-shell?

Comment: @Karsta Make that a new question! :)

Comment: @dan, you've [edited my answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/246953/3) with the statement that it is now built-in in 5.8+, but how do we use it?

Comment: @gertvdijk: no idea... I haven't tried KDE after the [silly amount of bugs I found](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=135101&p=363293#p363293) in it within the first few hours. This blog claims that [modifier-only shortcuts are working in Plasma 5.8](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2016/08/modifier-only-shortcuts-available-in-plasma-5-8/).

Comment: Update for 2017 - the solution provided below by Murupoicy (Mapping to META - F1) works fine here out of the box.

Comment: *Nothing* works on KDE Neon. By nothing, i mean that assigning your own shortcut never ever does anything. It's plain broken. Note that there's no shortcut by default because you will certainly have replaced the default weird menu with the alternate sane one.

Comment: this is outdated. later plasma versions come with Meta key as default and let you restore it if lost by selecting Meta-F1 as indicated in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/961407/47206)

Answer (score 159):

If you assign the launcher shortcut key to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, KDE will instead interpret this as assigning it to *solely* the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.

---

To open the settings window, <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the launcher icon and choose *Configure Application Launcher*. Then click on *Keyboard shortcuts* (as shown below).

After clicking *Apply*, the launcher should open when just pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>. This currently works on Plasma 5.24 and 5.25.

[image: Application Menu Settings window]

Comment: KDE Plasma 5.8.7, somehow crashed kde and the windows key didn't work anymore, but this fixed it.

Comment: On plasma 5.13.5 works as expected, should be selected answer.

Comment: Worked! for me worked after logout and login (ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: worked for me. it just now open with meta key

Comment: Does not work on Plasma **5.16.5**.

Comment: works on plazma 5.18.5

Comment: This does not work for me and I'm on Plasma 5.18.5, too. _Meta-F1_ will open the menu, but not just _Meta_. There must  be more to it.

Comment: Works for me in 5.18.5 (just adding Meta-F1, not editing ~/.config/kwinrc)

Comment: Works on Plasma **5.20.4**

Comment: Works on Plasma **5.21.2**.

Comment: works, but you can assign ALT+F1 to Application Launcher then Meta will work too. https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma_application_launchers/en

Comment: Works, but ***WHY***??? This is such a stupid solution lmao

Comment: 5.23.4 and it's gone again

Comment: Works on Plasma 5.25.5... weird.

Comment: Was working on 5.27 but I "lost it" somehow.  This hack worked.  It does seem to be a hack though.

Answer (score 27):

It doesn't do exactly what you are asking for, but ALT-Space opens a search box with which you can launch basically the stuff you could select from the Application Launcher.

Comment: Was exactly what I was looking for and I didnt even know.

Comment: Such an underutilized feature IMO, from someone who's default action, is to strike the meta whenever launching an application.

Comment: that's still 2 keys, for a super-common feature.

Comment: Agreed, this answer does not perfectly answer the question, but ALT + SPACE works perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 14):

Feature has been added by default since Plasma 5.8.
If it's not working, make sure your "Start Menu" widget has a global shortcut like Alt+F1 set.
You can't assign it directly to Meta, but it will open with Meta if another shortcut is assigned).

```
Right Click the KDE Icon → Application Menu Settings
Keyboard Shortcuts Tab → Shortcut: Alt+F1
```

Latte Dock:

If you're using Latte Dock, you will need to run the following commands mentioned in it's Wiki.

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta  "org.kde.lattedock,/Latte,org.kde.LatteDock,activateLauncherMenu"
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#open-start-menu-with-windows-meta-key

Comment: Very nice. This is my experience. After upgrade things sstopped working. I had two places to set shortcut for launcher widget. Had to move from one to the other so that win key started to work again. My credit to https://superuser.com/q/1588474/111432

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Latte panel and this works well

Answer (score 5):

simple workaround without loosing meta: meta + z (u.s. layout)

can be hit with just one finger at one

Comment: Simple and effective!!!

Comment: I like this workaround since with `ksuperkey` there is a lag when closing the menu by tapping Super twice.

Comment: As of KDE Plasma 5.5.5, this doesn't work. Worse, if you press Meta+z in the terminal, you'll get some odd string.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Plasma 5.8.5 and I can enable this feature by going to System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced -> The third checkbox should be "Alt/Win key behavior" -> Choose "Meta is mapped to Win keys" -> Apply

You are all set :)

Comment: On my system (Kubuntu 18.04 LTS) there're two alternatives: `Meta is mapped to Left Win` and `Meta is mapped to Win`. I tried both, but neither of them worked.

Comment: No effect for me... same result as code_dredd

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer may have worked a few years ago, `ksuperkey` does not seem to work on Kubuntu 15.10, when installed from PPA. I have no doubt ksuperkey is a better solution, but I ended up following the link in gertvdjik's answer and using [this solution](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=39073&sid=01f041447c5d994092581e9988df8763#p215019), which works absolutely fine. Posting here for future googlers who had the same trouble as I did.

For brevity;

> NOTICE: YOU WILL LOSE THE META KEY - so you might want to map it
> somewhere else.
>
> Run `xev | grep keycode` press the meta key and watch the output (the
> code is likely 115)
>
> then add an entry to your Xmodmap configuration:
>
> ```
> echo 'keycode 115 = F13' > ~/.Xmodmap
> ```
>
> "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" will change the keysym to F13 (not present on
> most keyboards ;-) and you can use it like any regular key.
>
> If your distro does (probably) not invoke ~/.Xmodmap by default, add a
> short script to `~/.kde/share/autostart/xmodmap.sh`
>
> ```
> xmodmap.sh:
> #!/bin/sh xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
> ```
>
> and make it executable `chmod +x ~/.kde/share/autostart/xmodmap.sh`

Comment: I receive this error : cat: keycode 115 = F13: No such file or directory

Comment: @Woeistg You might try replacing that line with `echo "keycode 115 = F13" >> ~/.Xmodmap`, the important thing is that the `~/.Xmodmap` file contain that line. If that works for you i can edit the post.

Comment: Note: ksuperkey works on Plasma 5.7, built from source (KDE Neon with Ubuntu 16.04 base)

Answer (score 3):

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.plasmashell,/PlasmaShell,org.kde.PlasmaShell,activateLauncherMenu"
```

works most of the time for me. It adds the setting to the kwin config file. This means it defines a new so called "ModifierOnlyShortcurt", which is just the Meta key to activate the launcher menu.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows + Enter</kbd> worked (Kubuntu: 22.04/KDE Plasma: 5.24.6).

### Steps:

1. Right click on `Application Launcher` icon, select `Configure Application Launcher`.

[image]

2. Go to `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab and click on `Input ...` button.

[image]

3. Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys on the keyboard.

(<kbd>Windows</kbd> = <kbd>Meta</kbd> = <kbd>Super</kbd> = same key.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> = <kbd>Return</kbd> = same key)

4. It should look like this

[image]

5. Finally, click on `Ok` to save the configuration and test.

Comment: Finally a solution that works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This soultion worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install git gcc make libx11-dev libxtst-dev pkg-config
git clone https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey.git
cd ksuperkey
make
./ksuperkey
```

then make it to start every-time your computer boots up.

[source](http://blog.hanschen.org/2012/10/17/open-application-launcher-with-super-key/)

Comment: Doesn't work on Kubuntu 19.04 anymore

Answer (score 1):

Running the "If you wish to revert..." commands [from here](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#Windows.2FMeta_Key) fixed it for me in the latest Kubuntu after I 'broke' it switching to a custom doc.

Comment: it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution don't use the Meta key but you can use only the Menu key for the shortcut.

[image: The Menu key]

Comment: doesn't work on my laptop

Comment: We have 2020 now, it should be possible to use the meta key.

Answer (score 0):

I have also be confused about this question weeks ago.
Today I added a panel and a `Tiled Menu` on it. Then I use alt+F5 to activate it.
Beacuse alt+F1 F2 F3 F4 are alreadly occupied. Really, not alt+F1.
It happened just after reboot that the <kbd>Super</kbd> was back to life!
So I think that:

```
The one on Latte Dock won't work.
The one on a default panel will do.
```

It's interesting.
KDE Plasma Version:5.14.5
KDE Frameworks Version:5.54.0
Debian 10.3

Answer (score 0):

It just randomly stopped working today for me.  Had to right click the Application Launcher (start menu) > Configure > Assign a new keyboard shortcut 'Meta + Z' because some ditzy person decided to disable the option to just use Meta (That I can assure you was deliberate) Then.  Boom!  It started working with just Meta and also Meta + Z.

What a silly solution all because KDE has dementia and can't remember what happened 5 minutes ago.  History in Konsole, Screen layouts, etc etc. There are many such examples.