# Search panel in KDE

Tags: kde

I recently installed KDE. In unity when i press the "Windows key"  or "meta key" I get a search panel where I can search for any programs or files or even it gets results from Web. In KDE I am not able to launch it by pressing the key. Pls help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open the Application Launcher on KDE with just the meta ("Windows") key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246886/how-do-i-open-the-application-launcher-on-kde-with-just-the-meta-windows-key)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as the OP ignored the existence of the KDE launcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search/program start bar in KDE can be started with

```
Alt + F2
```

and program launcher

```
Alt + F1
```

These are defaults. You can change these keys in:

System settings > Shortcuts and  gesture